# How to insert multiple records in different rows in prepared statement php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, insert

I have inserted some strings with values in one table lets call it `table_1` in my database, now I have arrays which I want to insert into separate rows in `table_2` in my SQL database.

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . $table_1 . '(shipping_fee, waybill_status, pickup_fee, ) 
        VALUES(:shipping_fee, :waybill_status, :pickup_fee)';

$stmt = $this->dbConn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':shipping_fee', $s_shipping_fee);
$stmt->bindParam(':waybill_status', $s_waybill_status);
$stmt->bindParam(':pickup_fee', $this->pickup_fee);

if($stmt->execute()){ //THIS INSERTED THE STRINGS PERFECTLY
    //NOW ALL VALUES TO BE INSERT INTO $sqal is an array

    $sqal = 'INSERT INTO ' . $table_2. '(id, waybill_number, client_id, item_name, item_weight, item_length, item_width, item_category, date_added) VALUES(null, :waybill_numberr, :client_idaa, :item_name, :item_weight, :item_length, :item_width, :item_category, :date_added)';

    $stmtaaa = $this->dbConn->prepare($sqal);
    $stmtaaa->bindParam(':item_name', $this->item_name); //ARRAY
    $stmtaaa->bindParam(':item_weight', $this->item_weight); //ARRAY
    $stmtaaa->bindParam(':item_length', $this->item_length); //ARRAY
    $stmtaaa->bindParam(':item_width', $this->item_width); //ARRAY
    $stmtaaa->bindParam(':item_category', $this->item_category); //ARRAY

    $stmtaaa->execute(); //HoW do I go about this.
} else {
    echo "Could not insert";
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to bind and execute an array as opposed to a string?

Comment: How are those arrays indexed - numbered from 0 to n?

Comment: @qirel yes, that the question.

Comment: @qirel i have binded the first prepared execute statement

Comment: @qirel, yes the array is from 0 upward when i do print_r(item_name)

Comment: @qirel, yes the array is from 0 upward when i do print_r(item_name)

Comment: @matt Okay Matt thanks for the point out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a syntax error in your first query, the trailing commas `,` should not be there in the column- or value-list.

You can insert an array by executing the prepare multiple times with different values. This example assumes that all your arrays are indexed by numbers (from zero and up).

The code example above also binds more columns than it binds, so you need to bind a value to each column. `waybill_numberr`, `client_idaa` and `date_added` are missing its binds (I just added some random placeholders).

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table_1 (shipping_fee, waybill_status, pickup_fee) 
        VALUES (:shipping_fee, :waybill_status, :pickup_fee)";

$stmt = $this->dbConn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':shipping_fee', $s_shipping_fee);
$stmt->bindParam(':waybill_status', $s_waybill_status);
$stmt->bindParam(':pickup_fee', $this->pickup_fee);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
    $sqal = "INSERT INTO $table_2 (id, waybill_number, client_id, item_name, item_weight, item_length, item_width, item_category, date_added) 
             VALUES (null, :waybill_numberr, :client_idaa, :item_name, :item_weight, :item_length, :item_width, :item_category, :date_added)";

    $stmtaaa = $this->dbConn->prepare($sqal);

    foreach ($this->item_weight as $key => $value) {
        $stmtaaa->execute(["waybill_numberr" => '1',   // Change this to your actual value
                           "client_idaa" => '1',       // Change this to your actual value
                           "item_name" => $value, 
                           "item_weight" => $this->item_weight[$key],
                           "item_length" => $this->item_length[$key],
                           "item_width" => $this->item_width[$key],
                           "item_category" => $this->item_category[$key],
                           "date_added" => '1']);
    }
} else {
    echo "Could not insert";
    exit();
}
```